# Problem with keyboard on netbook

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Im having some trouble with the keyboard on an acer aspire one netbook. 
It has a dansih keyboard, but the keyboard behaves strange.
When i push the w key it writes wr, if i push the w key again it writes rw
If i press the a key it writes af, if i push the a key againg it writes fa
the right shift key writes -
the fn key writes <

The keyboard driver claims to be a standard 101/102 key or microsoft PS/2 keyboard

The OS is Win XP

Comment: There is still warranty on the netbook, so Ill send it back to the shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keyboard is almost certainly broken, however it is worth cleaning first to see if that fixes it.

***Only do this if you are prepared to buy a new keyboard!***

Remove the keyboard from the laptop. Completely immerse in a bowl of warm water and agitate for a few minutes. Remove from the water and dry in a warm area for at least 24 hours. Be sure that there is no water left before plugging it back into your laptop.

If it is dirst causing problems, this usually works. It may be an electrical problem in which case a new keyboard is your only option.

Comment: er.. built in keyboard- washing it might be a BAD idea

Comment: if it's removable, I'd use isopropyl alcohol instead of water - helps get the gunk off, and dries much faster

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is the laptop that is some how damaged.

About three weeks ago, a friend had a very similar problem - pressing `n` came out as `nnnnnnnrrrrr` (no idea if that is the same place on qwerty as on Danish layout?).

I bought a replacement and spent time replacing it, only to discover the new one did the same.

I have no idea what is wrong, but I am almost certain that it is a manufacturing problem at Acer.

My friend uses an external keyboard through USB that works fine - if not a bit annoying.

(The worst thing was, this was out of warranty - when it was still in warranty, my friend sent it back for a different problem relating to audio - they sent it back with the username "ownnnnnnnnrrrrer" or similar - basically, they tried to type "owner". I have no idea why they didn't spot it, and then as by then it was out of warranty, they refused to fix it...)